# Determine whether $ARGV[X] is passed a string or a file in perl.

Tags: perl

Is there a way, other than checking for suffixes? Or should I stick with checking for .txt?

Comment: You might get up votes (or at least less down votes) if this question was worded more clearly (and in a way that is more useful for search engines). Hint: try to make it match the response from @fin.

Comment: @Mabeuf: I have rolled your question back to the original because I think it is even less clear what you mean if you don't mention `@ARGV` at all. It also made the answer you have accepted seem rather strange

Comment: I was trying to do what G. Cito said above. I thought my question was clear. I was expecting a line such as `my $in= $ARGV[1] or die $usage unless ......`

and thought my title explained the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@ARGV` is just a list of command-line arguments provided to the script, see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

If you want to know whether one of those arguments is a file, you probably want `-e`, see [file tests](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

If you expect the first argument to be a filename, something like:

```
my $filename = shift @ARGV;
die "script.pl FILENAME expected" unless -e $filename;
```